# Regular expressions in Terraform

Tags: regex, terraform

I need to use regular expressions in my Terraform code. The [documentation for the replace function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#replace_string_search_replace_) says the string if wrapped in a forward slash can be treated as a regex.

I've tried the following:

```
Name = "${replace(var.string, var.search | lower(var.search), replace)}"
```

I need to use regex to replace either the string or the lower case of the string with the replace string.

Comment: Well, what did you actually use and see? Did you try within `//`

Comment: Yes, I tried using strings between the / slashes like /"str1 | str2"/ and "/str1 | str2/" also "/str1/str2" , but none will replace str1 or str2 with the replacing string.

Comment: Did you try /regex/i

Comment: can you be more specific please? don't get what i or regex stand for there

Comment: Usually `i` is the flag to do case insensitive match. Try `/str1/i`

Comment: doesn't work in here

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Terraform docs for the [replace function](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#replace_string_search_replace_) state that you need to wrap your search string in forward slashes for it to search for a regular expression and this is also seen in the [code](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/549cff5/config/interpolate_funcs.go#L742).

Terraform uses the [re2 library](https://github.com/google/re2) to handle regular expressions which does supposedly take a `/i` flag to make it case insensitive. However I couldn't seem to get that to work at all (even trying `/search/i/`) but it does support [Perl style regular expressions](https://github.com/google/re2/blob/master/re2/re2.h#L30) unless in POSIX mode so simply prefixing your search variable with `(?i)` should work fine.

A basic worked example looks like this:

```
variable "string"  { default = "Foo" }
variable "search"  { default = "/(?i)foo/" }
variable "replace" { default = "bar" }

resource "aws_instance" "example" {
  ami           = "ami-123456"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "${replace(var.string, var.search, var.replace)}"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One more example - removing the period from the end of the "string" variable:

```
variable "string"  { default = "Foo." }

"${replace("var.string", "\\.$", "")}"
```

Comment: For me it only works without the quotes around the var, thus:
`"${replace(var.string, "\\.$", "")}"`

Answer (score 2):

Just to help someone else looking here...   following the Terraform documentation:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/replace.html

To be recognized as a Regex, you need to put the pattern between / (slashes), like this:

```
 > replace("hello world", "/w.*d/", "everybody")
 > hello everybody
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is: `"${replace(var.string, "/\\.$/", "")}"`

Answer (score 1):

I created a Go Playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/T3KGburfZcw that emulates the `replace` function.  I am using an older version of Terraform, but it should still work for newer versions.  Hope this is helpful for others that have struggled to debug a regex.

Comment: This is a very useful tool, thank you !

Comment: Glad it helped you!